# Use jquery validate() to with radio buttons and javascript variables

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

Im new to the jquery validate() plugin and I'm kind of lost here. So, what I want to do is to check if the selected radio button is equal to a variable:

So, lets say I have this in the form:

```
<input name = "radio_btns" value = "five" type = "radio">5
<input name = "radio_btns" value = "eight" type = "radio">8
```

I want to validate it to make sure the "five" option is selected, and I want to use a Javascript variable. I tried this, it is kind of obvious it won't work, anyway:

```
<script>
var required_answer = "five";
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#theform').validate({
    rules: {
        radio_btns: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: required_answer        <--- problem here ¬.¬
        }
...
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you always want to make sure only Five shuld be selected correct?

Comment: No, sometimes it will be a different option. But it will be useful to know how to check Five is selected in the first place, I'm lost in their documentation.

Comment: I am making code for FIVE must be selected . Then u will do rest on ur own , ok?

Comment: Thanks man, I will vote you up, but I can't accept your answer since the question refers to how to use a javascript variable for validation, in such a way that the "correct" option could change: sometimes it will be "five", sometimes "eight".

Comment: why dont post jsFiddle ,so that i will have to waste less time .Please post jsFiffle if you want answer fast

Comment: Hello , You mean Atleast one Radio button shuld be selected no matter its Eight or Five . Correct? Form shoul submit Only when Atleast 1 radio button is checked . Corrcet?

Comment: Please tell what else u want other than this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NX43L/

Comment: Did u check here http://jqueryvalidation.org/equalTo-method/  ? EqualTo means to check values of Two inputs (say Textboxes). Just like PASSWORD, and PASSWORD again .Both should hav same value ,so password_again will have attribute equalTo pointing towards password .

Comment: I don't need a long answer for that part of the question. Maybe you can just comment it here, how can I make sure the option is equal to "five"? `rules: {required:true, equalTo: "five"}` is what I have.

Comment: @PratikJoshi Thanks for your help, just checked your fiddle. What need is that if the user selects 5, the form is valid, if he selects 8, then it is invalid.

Comment: OK NOW bingo check this fiddle :) http://jsfiddle.net/NX43L/2/

Comment: @PratikJoshi I did check the equalTo documentation. I couldn't find a way to make a simple validation like the one I need, so I tested `equalTo`. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: OK NOW bingo check this fiddle :) jsfiddle.net/NX43L/2

Comment: sorry i forgot to paste it in Answer , it will be usful for future people .Thanks :) please do +1 and accept answer if it solves ur problem

Comment: Thanks @PratikJoshi If you want, post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NX43L/2/)

Use following custom method

//HTML

```
<form id="theform">
    <input name = "radio_btns" value = "five" type = "radio"/>5
    <input name = "radio_btns" value = "eight" type = "radio"/>8

    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

//jQuery part

Check here the value of Radio button user selected is "Five" , if its five then return TRUE else FALSE . So if true returned then Submit form (or say if Five selected) ,else Dont .

```
$(document).ready(function(){

jQuery.validator.addMethod("selectFive", function(value, element) 
{    var required_answer = "five";
    if(value == required_answer) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}, "Please select five.");    

// validate the comment form when it is submitted
    $("#theform").validate({
        errorElement: 'div',
        rules: {

            radio_btns: {
                required: true,
                selectFive: true            

            }
        },
        messages: {

            radio_btns: {
                required: "Please select."  
            }

        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo( element.parent() );
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            jQuery('input[type=submit]', form).attr('disabled', 'disabled');            
            form.submit();

        }
    });
});
```